# Add two Numbers(Using ListNode)

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode() {
    }

    ListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode();
        int car = 0;

        while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if (l1.next == null && l2.next != null) {
                l3.val = (l2.val +l1.val+ car) % 10;
                car = (l2.val+l1.val + car) / 10;
                l2 = l2.next;

            } else if (l2.next == null && l1.next != null) {
                l3.val = (l1.val +l2.val+ car) % 10;
                car = (l1.val +l2.val+ car) /10;
                l1 = l1.next;

            } else {
                l3.val = (l1.val + l2.val + car) % 10;
               car = (l1.val + l2.val + car) / 10;

                l1 = l1.next;
                l2 = l2.next;
                if (l1 != null || l2 != null) {
                    l3.next = new ListNode();
                    l3 = l3.next;
                }
                if (l1 == null && l2 == null && car != 0) {
                    l3.next = new ListNode(car);
                    l3 = l3.next;
                }
            }
        }
        return l3;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode ll = new ListNode(1);
        ll.next = new ListNode(1);
        //ll.next.next = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode l2 = new ListNode(1);
        l2.next = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode l3 = addTwoNumbers(ll, l2);
        ListNode temp = l3;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.val+"." );
            temp = temp.next;

        }
    }
}
```

Here I noticed only one node of `l3` where there must be two ListNodes with their `l3.val`= 2 here second ListNode itself not created for l3 ,but as I saw while debugging the loop runs two times..explain me how..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your `l3` reference moves along the newly created linked list, but thereby you lose the reference to the **first** node of that linked list. With `return l3` you always return the **last** node of that linked list, which then is a list with just one node.

There are some other issues in your code also:

- If `l1` and `l2` are not of equal length the loop will use the value of the last node in the shortest list multiple times, *and* the same `l3.val` is overwritten, leading to wrong results. In other words, as soon as `l1.val` is **used** in a sum, `l1 = l1.next` must be executed to avoid double counting.
- A new node is always created *ahead* of the next iteration of the loop, which makes the logic overly complex.

Proposed code:

```
    public static ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(); // This is a dummy node
        ListNode tail = l3; // l3 will not move, but tail will.
        int car = 0;

        while (l1 != null || l2 != null || car > 0) { // Work to do?
            // Avoid code repetition and deal with all cases together
            int sum = (l1 == null ? 0 : l1.val) + (l2 == null ? 0 : l2.val) + car;
            // Leave l3 at the root, and only move tail
            tail = tail.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            car = sum / 10;
            if (l1 != null) l1 = l1.next;
            if (l2 != null) l2 = l2.next;
        }
        return l3.next; // Skip first dummy node
    }
```

Here the initial node that is created for `l3` is not actually used to store a meaningful value. For every meaningful value a new node is created on-the-spot and at the end the dummy node is skipped in the returned linked list.